# Connecting to Oracle SQL Developer locally on Mac?

Tags: oracle, mac-os-x

I'm trying to connect to Oracle SQL Developer locally on my Mac. How exactly is this done? I've looked all over the network, and can't find anything helpful.

The only thing I did is installing the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer.

I have an assignment due tomorrow and cannot work from labs today.

Comment: Are you on the same network that the database server is on?

Comment: hmmm, actually I want to have the database on my machine. So, I can use it locally with no internet . This is my first time installing Oracle on my machine instead of using the labs.

Comment: I don't think they don't have Oracle 11G for os-x.  You may need to use a virtual machine.

Comment: There hasn't been a server version of Oracle available for Mac OS X for some time now. Sorry. You'll have to use a Linux virtual machine. Best that you close this question. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Developer doesn't come with an Oracle database, it is a client application. You can't "connect to SQL Developer", you *use* SQL Developer to connect to an existing database.

There are no supported editions of Oracle database for Mac OS X at this time, the latest that was available was 10gR2. You'll need to set one up in a VM on your machine (Windows or Linux, using the Oracle XE edition seems like it would fit your need), or see if you can somehow connect to your lab databases (possibly via a VPN to your school if they have that available).

Comment: I run into the same problem, but in different environment. How can I create an oracle database server?